# Passing strings in Sql query from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I Have a sql query as below:

```
Select CatId 
From tbl_T2H_Category 
Where Category IN ('Category3', 'Category4', 'Category6')
```

Now what i want is the values inside IN clause should be added dynamically from the checkboxlist. I am getting comma separated values from my control and passing that to the sql query like this:

```
string mystring = "Category3,Category4,Category6";
cmd.commanText = "Select CatId From tbl_T2H_Category Where Category IN (" + mystring + ")";
```

This is not executing on sql side, because sql only recognises strings if they are inside "'" "'"  (single quotes). Kindly help me write the appropriate query.

Comment: Step 1, learn about parameterised queries.

Comment: What version of sql server? Later versions have a better way of handling this.

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 R2

Comment: This looks like an old request for free work, and once people supplied that free work, you did not reply anyway. Please always reply to the people who assist you.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use a Table-Value Parameter. The MSDN article shown here demonstrates it better than I can:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Comment: +1 for not proposing the obvious, dangerous  `SELECT 'INJECT' + 'ME' FROM Table`

Answer (score 3):

This is best dealt with using [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Your first step is to create the type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList AS TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);
```

Your next step is to create a datatable in c# from your comma separated list to pass to your SqlCommand:

```
string mystring = "Category3,Category4,Category6";
string[] myarray = mystring.Split(",".ToCharArray());

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < myarray.Length; i++)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row[0] = myarray[i];
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Finally you can pass this to your SqlCommand:

```
cmd.commanText = "Select CatId From tbl_T2H_Category Where Category IN (SELECT Value FROM @Strings)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Strings", SqlDbType.Structured)).Value = table;
```

Answer (score 2):

correct syntax

```
string mystring = "'Category3','Category4','Category6'";
cmd.commanText = "Select CatId From tbl_T2H_Category Where Category IN (" + mystring + ")";
```

but please dont use it this was. you can use it like below(but this is not recommended as well)

```
cmd.commanText = "Select CatId From tbl_T2H_Category Where Category IN ('" + cat_1 + "','" + cat_2 + "','" + cat_3 + "')";
```

I would use this one below, it is alot secure

```
string commandText = "Select CatId From tbl_T2H_Category Where Category IN (@cat_1,@cat_2 @cat_3)";
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
 command.Parameters.Add("@cat1", SqlDbType.Varchar);
 command.Parameters["@cat1"].Value = "category1";
 command.Parameters.Add("@cat2", SqlDbType.Varchar);
 command.Parameters["@cat2"].Value = "category2";
 command.Parameters.Add("@cat3", SqlDbType.Varchar);
 command.Parameters["@cat3"].Value = "category3";
```

this last one is much secure, it prevents sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap every category in string with single quote?

Something like

```
var mystring = "'Category3','Category4','Category6'"
```

Comment: This will leave him open to sql injection.

Comment: And be sure there is no way, user can forge category values - i.e. if user can submit category with name ';drop table Category;-- you're in trouble

Answer (score 0):

Split your comma separated values into an array with

```
 string[] myArr = commaSepString.Split(',');
```

and then join them with commas, surrounded by commas like this

```
 string newString = "'"+myArr.Join("','")+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public String returnCategories(string categories) 
    {
        string categoriesConc = "";

        string[] split = categories.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoriesConc))
            {
                categoriesConc = split[i].ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                categoriesConc = categoriesConc + "," + split[i].ToString();
            }
        }

        return categoriesConc;
    }
```